# Android Как получить время, отображаемое в StatusBar

Tags: java, android, время, calendar, timezone

Здравствуйте!

Некоторые пользователи при переходе на постоянное зимнее время отключили синхронизацию времени и часового пояса по сети и вручную перевели время на час назад.

Сейчас у них на телефонах, к примеру, установлен часовой пояс, в котором 14:00, а на телефоне отображается текущее время 13:00.

При получении времени методами

```
System.currentTimeMillis(), Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()
```

возвращает 14:00. Как получить время пользователя правильно?

Comment: мне почемуто всегда казалось что Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() возвращает время с уже примененными настройками часовых поясов, вы не перепутали ?

Comment: Часовой пояс выставлен верно, не учитывается разница во времени, заданная вручную.

Answer (score 2):

Всё, что я смог найти, сведено вот в этот [пост](https://pristalovpavel.wordpress.com/2015/08/13/how-to-get-the-real-device-time-with-wrong-time-zone/).

**Резюме**: без использования дополнительных запросов к серверу и/или получения собственных координат (которые не всегда могут быть доступны), невозможно получить необходимую разницу во времени.

Это же относится и к отменённому летнему времени: часть устройств всё ещё считает, что летом часовой пояс Москвы `GMT+4`, часть - уже знает, что `GMT+3`. И кроме запроса на сервер в общем случае никаким образом их не синхронизировать.

Answer (score 1):

Нет возможности проверить, но думаю нужно получить таймзону и посчитать с ней?

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
```

или попробовать другой способы:

```
Time now = new Time();
now.setToNow();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но текущая временная зона уже используется, необходимо как раз получить разницу между этим временем и временем в приложении "Часы". От Time советует отказаться сам Google (deprecated since API 21)

Answer (score 1):

`Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()` возвращает количество миллисекунд в часовом поясе UTC. Как вы проверяете что это соответвует 14:00? Может быть, пользователь не переводил время, а поставил себе соседний часовой пояс? 
В любом случае попробуйте проверить какой час возвращается если использовать `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)`

Comment: Нет, это проблема у многих людей. Описана на глобальном Stack Overflow и средствами Android там не решена. Мы пофиксили с помощью сервера, сейчас тестим. Как обкатаем - опишу наш подход.